# when i run appRoleAssignments, it returns the unclear response

Tags: c#, azure, microsoft-graph-api, office365api

I tried to assign appRole to servicePrincipal and got some weird response: 
the url is 
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/servicePrincipals/{id}/appRoleAssignments
with

```
{
  "principalDisplayName": "[displayName]",
  "principalId": "[Guid]",
  "principalType": "ServicePrincipal",
  "resourceDisplayName": "Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory",
  "resourceId": "a774ef19-d0c7-4305-8317-8aa6a1f06634"
}
```

here is the response

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "Write requests are only supported on contained entities",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "2be2ae24-a9d9-4699-b72a-68f2feb12f8d",
            "date": "2017-08-17T18:10:07"
        }
    }
}
```

if I changed the url to 
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/appRoleAssignments
with the same request body, it returns

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Request_ResourceNotFound",
        "message": "Resource 'CBVUPR3WYk-2780vOjxKdw' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "9b1aaae6-3178-4db3-8a2b-1a025d69bbda",
            "date": "2017-08-17T18:18:05"
        }
    }
}
```

any idea about this?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I think this is very broken at present.  This API has a major bug in it - in that the API doesn't expose a way for you to set the appRoleId that you are trying to assign.  I don't have an ETA for when this will be fixed.  In the meantime, AAD Graph API is the only available option.

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thanks Dan, and please let me know if it is available.